# context switching with 'yield'

Tags: python, gevent

I was reading a gevent tutorial and saw this interesting snippet:

```
import gevent

def foo():
    print('Running in foo')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    print('Explicit context switch to foo again')

def bar():
    print('Explicit context to bar')
    gevent.sleep(0)
    print('Implicit context switch back to bar')

gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(foo),
    gevent.spawn(bar),
])
```

In which the flow of execution goes like this foo -> bar -> foo -> bar .
Is it not possible to do the same without the gevent module but with yield statements?
I've been trying to do this with 'yield' but for some reason I can't get it to work... :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generators used for this purpose are often called *tasks* (among many other terms), and I'll use that term here for clarity. Yes, it is possible. There are, in fact, several approaches that work and make sense in some contexts. However, none (that I'm aware of) work without an equivalent for at least one of `gevent.spawn` and `gevent.joinall`. The more powerful and well-designed ones require an equivalent for both.

The fundamental problem is this: Generators can be suspended (when they hit `yield`), but that's it. To kick them off again, you need some other code calling `next()` on them. In fact, you even need to call `next()` on a freshly-created generator for it to do *anything* to begin with.
Similarly, the generator itself isn't the best place to decide what should run next. So you need what is a loop that initiates each tasks's time slice (runs them to the next `yield`) and switches between them, indefinitely. This is usually called a scheduler. They tend to become really hairy really quickly, so I won't attempt to write a full scheduler in one answer. There are however some core concepts I can try to explain:

- One usually treats `yield` as giving control back to the sheduler (in effect similar to `gevent.sleep(0)` in your code). That means, the generator does whatever it wants to do, and when it's in a place where a context switch is convenient and possibly useful, it `yield`s.
- In Python 3.3+, `yield from` is a very useful tool to delegate to another generator. If you can't use it, you have to make the scheduler emulate a call stack and route return values to the right place, and do things like `result = yield subtasks()` in your tasks. This is slower, more complex to implement, and unlikely to yield useful stack traces (`yield from` does this for free). But until recently, it was the best we had.
- Depending on your use case, you may need a wide range of tools to manage tasks. Common examples are spawning more tasks, waiting for a task to complete, waiting for any one of several tasks to complete, detecting failure (uncaught exception) of other tasks, etc. These are usually handled by the scheduler and the tasks are given an API to communicate with the scheduler. A neat (but not always perfect) way to do this communication is `yield`ing special values.
- One rather important difference between generator-based tasks and gevent (and similar libraries) is that context switches in the latter are implicit, while tasks make it trivial to identify context switches: Only things that `yield [from]` can possibly run scheduler code. For example, you can make sure whether a piece of code is atomic (w.r.t. other tasks; if you add threads to the mix, you have to worry about them independently) just by looking at the code, without inspecting *anything* it calls.

Finally, you may be interested in Greg Ewing's [tutorial](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python/generators/yf_current/Examples/Scheduler/scheduler.txt) on creating such a scheduler. (This came up on `python-ideas` while brainstorming over what now is PEP 3156. These mail threads may also be of interest to your, though the web-based archive is not really suited to reading hundreds of mails in dozens of threads written half a year ago.)

Comment: Very interesting. Lots of things I did not know about. That tutorial seems nice too. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The key is to realise that you will have to provide your own driving loop—I have provided a simple demo below. I was lazy and used a Queue object to provide a FIFO, I haven't used python for a significant project for a while.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Queue

def foo():
    print('Constructing foo')
    yield
    print('Running in foo')
    yield
    print('Explicit context switch to foo again')

def bar():
    print('Constructing bar')
    yield
    print('Explicit context to bar')
    yield
    print('Implicit context switch back to bar')

def trampoline(taskq):
    while not taskq.empty():
        task = taskq.get()
        try:
            task.next()
            taskq.put(task)
        except StopIteration:
            pass

tasks = Queue.Queue()
tasks.put(foo())
tasks.put(bar())

trampoline(tasks)

print('Finished')
```

And when run:

```
$ ./coroutines.py 
Constructing foo
Constructing bar
Running in foo
Explicit context to bar
Explicit context switch to foo again
Implicit context switch back to bar
Finished
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the demo too. I was wondering whether it would be possible for a generatorA to yield next(generatorB)  (and generatorB to yield next(generatorA) and so on) .

Comment: The problem with that is three fold: The first is that I am unaware of any way for a generator to yield itself, which would be necessary to setup the mutual recursion. The second is that the call to next/0 needs to return before the yield statement will be evaluated, which will result in trying to reenter a generator that hasn't yielded yet. The third is that this is mutual recursion in a language without tail-call-elimination, so you will eventually exhaust the stack if the generators yield too many times.